# awk compare two columns in same file with letters in one column

Tags: awk

how todo column matching in same file. for e.g compare server and FQDN column. FQDN column has extra words so i couldn't find way to strip.

```
    "server","cpu","memory","disk","FQDN"
    "host1",4,32,100,"host2.xxx.com"
    "host2",2,10,20,"host2.xxx.com"
    "host3",6,4,100,"host1.xxx.com"
    "host4",2,10,30,"host4.xxx.com"
    "host5",3,6,32,"host3.xxx.com"
```

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /$5/' test.csv
```

```
expected results:
    "host1",4,32,100,"host2.xxx.com"
    "host3",6,4,100,"host1.xxx.com"
    "host5",3,6,32,"host3.xxx.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Test a substring of `$5` that has same length as `$1`:

```
 awk -F, 'substr( $5, 1, length($1) ) == $1' test.csv
```

Your "expected results" show lines where these fields **don't** match.  If that's what you want, do the same transformation but test for inequality instead:

```
 awk -F, 'substr( $5, 1, length($1) ) != $1' test.csv
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, my columns do have doublequotes in input file and is there anyway to exclude in awk. i could use sed before awk but asking if there is one liner via awk.
input file:
"server","cpu","memory","disk","FQDN"
"host1",4,32,100,"host2.xxx.com"
"host2",2,10,20,"host2.xxx.com"
"host3",6,4,100,"host1.xxx.com"
"host4",2,10,30,"host4.xxx.com"
"host5",3,6,32,"host3.xxx.com"

Answer (score 2):

***For getting matches:*** try following.

```
awk -F'[,.]' '$1==$5'  Input_file
```

***For getting NON matching:*** try following.

```
awk -F'[,.]' '$1!=$5' Input_file
```

OR to remove headers in output try:

```
awk -F'[,.]' 'FNR>1 && $1!=$5' Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Setting field separator as `,` or `.` for all lines in Input_file and then simply comparing `$1` and `$5`, for matching case using `==` condition and for NON matching case using `!=` condition.